# How this redirect works?

Tags: php, redirect, mobile, user-agent

I have this link
http://appflood.go2cloud.org/aff_c?offer_id=1724&aff_id=2593

It provides redirect on any browser in Android (Internal, Chrome, Firefox).
But it does not redirect on desktop browsers.

And this link CAN'T be fooled! So if I change useragent in my desktop Firefox to the string EXACTLY matching with mobile phone string, I can't get redirect.
Also if I switch ANY of my mobile browser to desktop mode, I am still being redirected.
I can fool ANY of common mobile detecting methods by changing UserAgent. But I can't fool this link.

So I suppose that the redirecting is based not on parsing UserAgent only.
Please note that I use my mobile phone with wifi, which connected to my router. So the phone have same external IP with my desktop computer. it is regarding version of detecting IP's of wireless ISP.

So, the question is: how this redirect works and how can I implement the similar.

Comment: We need to see the code for redirect :)

Comment: Normal redirect working by sending header redirect code to the browser like 301 or 302 and also sending the location to redirect to. for example in php its [ header("Location: http://example.com/");]

Comment: This link sends 302 on Android but does not send 302 on desktop.

Comment: After some research, this definitely seems like a network routing issue.

Comment: But why I get different results with same network?

Comment: I don't think it's the same network route though. When you try with mobile browsers, are you connected to the same wireless network that the desktop computers are?

Comment: Yes, I am connected to the same network by wifi. I wrote it in my question:)

Answer (score 0):

Using `curl` from the Bash command line:

```
$ curl -i 'http://appflood.go2cloud.org/aff_c?offer_id=1724&aff_id=2593'
HTTP/1.0 302 Moved
Location: http://10.42.217.107:15871/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws-session=356106294
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

And then requesting the redirect URL:

```
$ curl -i 'http://10.42.217.107:15871/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws-session=356106294'
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 800
Content-Type: image/gif

GIF87a...
```

I pasted this URL into Firefox 35.0 on Windows 7 (a laptop) and the redirect worked fine.

I don't see a problem here, unless you have cached versions of those URLs on the desktop browsers.

Edit #1: Added single quotes around the URL in the curl command so the `&` character does end the command prematurely.

Edit #2: I tried a `tracert` on appflood.go2cloud.org:

```
$ tracert appflood.go2cloud.org

Tracing route to appflood.go2cloud.org [54.175.84.195]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

   1     4 ms     1 ms     1 ms  <Internal Domain Name/IP>
 ...    ...      ...      ...    ...
  12    25 ms    25 ms    36 ms  198.71.46.9     (Ann Arbor, Michigan, USA)
  13    26 ms    26 ms    25 ms  72.21.220.29    (Amazon.com, Seattle, Washington, USA)
  14    26 ms    26 ms    26 ms  205.251.245.224 (Amazon.com, Seattle, Washington, USA)
  15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 ...    ...      ...      ...    ...
  30     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

(I left out internal IPs and domain names, and the myriad timeouts for brevity)

@axiac said in a comment below that the same problem was happening. This could be a regional network routing issue, as I am in the USA and it's working fine.

Comment: Your command line didn't ask the URL in the question. There is an ampersand (`&`) in it and that ends the command and tells `bash` to launch it in the background. Notice it's job number and its PID (`[1] 2784`) before the `curl`'a output. Put the URL between quotes or apostrophes to test it correctly.

Comment: Answer updated. The result was the same from the command line

Comment: hmm, i have different result:curl -i 'http://appflood.go2cloud.org/aff_c?offer_id=1724&aff_id=2593'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Thu, 15 Jan 2015 14:15:15 GMT
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.4.4
tracking_id: 102d83e26503603f3ebcaaff77c966
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: @SergeyKravchenko: That's interesting. I'm running a `tracert` on appflood.go2cloud.org right now. I'll update my answer with the results. I wonder if this is a networking issue? I'm currently in the state of Michigan, USA.

Comment: I also received '200 OK' without any content from both command line (using curl) and Firefox.

Comment: @axiac, judging by your StackOverflow profile, you are in Romania? I'm starting to thing this is a network routing issue.

Comment: Yes, I tried to access the page from Bucharest, Romania and also from a server from the Amazon cloud, I think it is physically located in Ireland. The result was the same, no redirection. Maybe the page uses geo location to find the country from the IP address and filters the requests by country.

Comment: I just did some [reverse IP lookups](http://ipaddress.com/reverse_ip/) and updated my answer. I'm jumping from Ann Arbor, Michigan, USA to the Amazon.com cloud in Seattle, Washington, USA. I think it's time to call Amazon.com Cloud support.